# Retreiving photos from mysql database using Flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, database, flask

I dont know where is my mistake . i am newbie on flask and i cant retrieve images from mysql database.

```
@app.route('/show')
def show():
    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
    sql="select *from upload "
    result=cur.execute(sql)
    if result>0:
        data=cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('show.html',imgfile=data)
```

```
{% for i in imgfile %}
   <img src="{{ i.photo }}" /> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to use `<img src="somethingOrOther">` is to put a static-file-fetching URL into the `src` variable. Something like this

```
    <img src="/img/myimage.png">
```

Then the browser hits your server with `https://example.com/img/myimage.png`, fetches the image, and renders it for you.

But, you can use a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) instead of a static-file URL. That is, you can put your image in-line into your html file. A data url for an image is a (very long) text string looking something like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,R0lGO5lhyAfD0QqZDs=
```

This string is made of the prefix `data:image/png;base64,` followed by the [base64-encoded](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#module-base64) image data.

Therefore your HTML output's `<img>` tag will look something like this:

```
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGO5lhyAfD0QqZDs=">
```

Notice my example says the image is a png. Yours may be something else. But browsers generally can figure out what kind of image they're given.

Also notice that html pages with embedded data URLs can be very large. Also, using data URLs defeats browsers' ability to cache images for future reuse without repeating the download.